# Can't pay 5$ registration fee for Chrome Web Store. How to find and contact responsible support?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying since weeks to get my first extension into the Chrome Web Store, but unfortunately my cards (as well as those of my partner) are not getting accepted.

I tried 4 different cards dozens of times. I also have a Visa card defined as standard in my Google payment center, with which I can make payments e.g. in Google play store, yet this same payment method does not get accepted for paying the 5$ 1-time developer registration fee.

The Google support pages are terrible and just send me in circles (while I haven't found any answers to my issue). Yet I cannot find any option to contact someone from the Web Store or from Google who could help me out here and look into my issue.

In the Chrome help forum in some similar cases, the answers suggested to contact this forum here or ["support"](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en). I did the latter and actually received a reply from a real person, but just to let me know they are not responsible but only for the Google Play Store, and forwarded me once again to the infinite loops of the Google Help pages.

Thus I am asking here if anyone knows how to get in touch with someone who is responsible for the registration fee payments or who can help me to finally get my registration fee paid.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried to search, call and email the support. I couldn't reach anyone who is in charge of the Chrome Web store. So the only solution for me, was to use another Google Account...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow is not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Also happening with me. Contrary to the previous comment, I support this question being on Stack Overflow because it seems to be more than just a "customer support" issue.